# Rotate polyshape based on centroid - matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image that I convert to a polyshape class, how can I rotate it based on a centroid point?
Code:

```
url='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/T/i/o/c/X/Q/airplane-md.png';
I = imread(url);
I = rgb2gray(I);
I = imcomplement(I);

imshow(I);
hold on;
BW = imbinarize(I);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
k=1;
stat = regionprops(I,'Centroid');
b = B{k};
c = stat(k).Centroid;
yBoundary = b(:,2);
xBoundary = b(:,1);
cy = c(:,2);
cx = c(:,1);

pgon1 = polyshape(yBoundary, xBoundary); 
plot(pgon1);
poly1 = rotate(pgon1,45);
plot(poly1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `polyshape.rotate` accepts an optional [third argument `refpoint`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.rotate.html#d120e948539) that will be the origin of the rotation:

```
% ...
b = B{k};
c = stat(k).Centroid;
pgon1 = polyshape(b(:,1), b(:,2)); 
poly1 = rotate(pgon1, 45, c);
```